# What does git log --exit-code mean?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

The [`git-log` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) describes the `--check` option as incompatible with the `--exit-code` option. I'd like to know what this `--exit-code` means but I can't find it anywhere. I've tried `man git log`, `man git`, Google and direct search here on SO... to no avail!

What does `--exit-code` mean for `git log`?

Comment: There are some limited ways that --exit-code can make sense with `log` (as opposed to `diff`) because log can act like diff, supporting flags like --ignore-whitesape, --ignore-space-at-eol, etc.  So even without -p (to print the patch) `git log -w -n 1 HEAD --exit-code` will give a different result depending if there are non-whitespace changes in the patch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL; DR

> I'd like to know what this `--exit-code` means [...]

`--exit-code` is a `diff-*`<sup>1</sup> option that makes the Git command exit with `1` if there are changes, and `0` otherwise.

> [...] but I can't find it anywhere.

You can read about it in the `git-diff` man page (it's only mentioned in passing in the `git-log` man page).

## More details

Both `--check` and `--exit-code` are described in the `git-diff` man page (more specifically, in [`Documentation/diff-options.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/diff-options.txt)):

> ```
>    --check
>  Warn if changes introduce whitespace errors. What are considered
>  whitespace errors is controlled by core.whitespace configuration.
>  By default, trailing whitespaces (including lines that solely
>  consist of whitespaces) and a space character that is immediately
>  followed by a tab character inside the initial indent of the line
>  are considered whitespace errors. Exits with non-zero status if
>  problems are found. Not compatible with --exit-code.
> ```

and

> ```
>    --exit-code
>  Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it
>  exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.
> ```

Some, though not all, `diff-*` options are compatible with `git-log`. The `--check` option is, whereas the `--exit-code` option is not, as hinted at by the following [commit message](https://github.com/git/git/commit/939ca96b0e871418ba5f43f0fe620d626305c67c) from the [Git-project repository](https://github.com/git/git):

> docs: don't mention `--quiet` or `--exit-code` in git-log(1)
>
> These are `diff`-options, but they don't actually make sense
>   in the context of `log`.

(1) <sub>`diff-*` stands for the plumbing commands that porcelain `git-diff` is based on.</sub>

Comment: `--exit-code` does make sense in the context of `log`, in particular when using `--grep`.

Comment: The only problem is that `git log --exit-code --grep=...` may find commits, but if they are empty, the exit code will still be `0`. Anyone has a better idea than checking if the `git log` output is an empty?

Comment: @DavidOngaro This answer is 8 years old. For more visibility, you may benefit from asking a new question that references this one.

Comment: @jub0bs Using `[[ $(git log --grep=something) ]]` is working for me. Having a proper exit code would enable me to get rid of the conditional expression and the command substitution, which are also bash specific. It would be a nice to have, but currently not important enough for me to open a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned in the [git-diff docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) (and is apparently not intended to be used with `git-log`):

> "Make the program exit with codes similar to diff(1). That is, it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences."